# logrotate reports "my_print_defaults: unknown option '--mariadbd'"

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb

My server is running Ubuntu 18.04.5  and I recently installed  mariadb 10.5.5 from the MariaDB repositories (not from the Ubuntu repositories where that version is not available yet).  Since then,  I get this error report from cron every day:

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
my_print_defaults: unknown option '--mariadbd'
```

The culprit is `/etc/logrotate.d/mysql-server` which calls `my_print_defaults --mariadbd`,  while `my_print_defaults` does not support the --mariadbd option.  Replacing --mariadbd by --mysqld fixes the problem. However, this is a file provided by the mariadb-server-10.5 package, and I would prefer not to edit it manually.

An internet search did not find any other reports of this issue.

Is this an error/bug in the mariadb configuration,  or am I using incompatible versions of something,  or what could be the cause of this error?

Here are some version details. Should I provide any other information?

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/my_print_defaults
mariadb-server-core-10.5: /usr/bin/my_print_defaults

$ dpkg -S etc/logrotate.d/mysql-server
mariadb-server-10.5: /etc/logrotate.d/mysql-server

$ mariadb -V
mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.5-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS \n \l
```

Comment: Apologies - it was a mistake - noted in [MDEV-22659](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-22659) to repair it.

Comment: @danblack would you consider the workaround as safe for a production environment? (Replacing `--mariadbd` by `--mysqld`)

Comment: Yes, its safe for production.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @danblack's comment,  I take it that this is a mistake in MariaDB that will be fixed in an upcoming version.

The workaround is to edit `/etc/logrotate.d/mysql-server` and replace --mariadbd by --mysqld

Comment: FYI  [upstream fix](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/commit/571bcf9aaaf59b84e24bbfb809738dea25495d78) being the same thing.